# bottomrule option not working in beamer tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I'd like to use the bottomrule option for the tcolorbox environment, as shown in the tcolorbox manual on page 12.

Unfortunately, the option does not seem to work, and the following code creates a standard tcolorbox instead of a bottomruled tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{\color{white}{\textbf{Introduction}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[bottomrule=3mm]
This should be a bottomruled \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The option should set the bottom boundary height to 3mm instead of the standard value (0.5mm), but it does not seem to do nothing. Similar options like `toprule`, `rightrule` and `leftrule` do not work, while `boxrule` (which sets the height of all boundaries) works.

[image]

Any idea what the problem may be?

---

After updating to the last version of `tcolorbox` the output is as expected

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you are seeing. I am no expert in this, but it appears to be working for me with TeXLive 2012.

Comment: I don't see a `bottomrule` key in `tcolorbox` (as a matter of fact, I don't see `toprule`, `rightrule` or `leftrule` either); according to the package documentation, there's a `boxrule` key to change the width of the whole frame.

Comment: I'm referring to this manual: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf pag. 12

Comment: Then, maybe you are using and outdated version of the package (as I am doing myself); you could update the package (I will do this right now).

Comment: Yes, after updating the package, your code works OK, so as I said in my previous comment, you must be using and outdated version and updating it should fix the problem.

Comment: yup, you're right, mine was outdated too. I was too confident in archlinux devs :D 
Thanks

Comment: @dcmst you're welcome! Then, if you don't mind, since the problem has been solved, most probably this question will be closed as "too localized".